# leftmost position change after next_permutation?

Tags: c++, algorithm, libstdc++

Using `std::next_permutation` is convenient but how do I know which position in the container is the leftmost that got changed, without keeping a copy and comparing every time (using `std::mismatch`)? That knowledge is probably somewhere in `std::next_permutation` so what would be a good implementation of it that can return also the value I need?

Alternatively, since for fixed `N` the sequence of these values is fixed too, how to implement a function (of `N`) that returns the wanted value when it's called every time `std::next_permutation` is called?

Comment: Why do you need to know if the "leftmost" element changed? What is the actual problem you want to solve?

Comment: I do not need to know if the leftmost element changed. In fact I know that this happens exactly after (n-1)! permutations if the start is sorted. I'm surprised your thoughtless question gets upvotes at all.

Comment: cppreference has a possible implementation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation sugguest you modify it to suit your needs.